# When should I change / replace my water pipe?

Tags: plumbing, water, pipe

I was wondering when should we change our indoor water pipe? Should we change every 5 years or every 10 years?

This is because recently, I notice that the water quality is not getting that good (cause my electric kettle have turn quite "rusty" when boiling the water).

By the way, I know that we can use water filtration system but was wondering if the pipe will accumulate unnecessary materials (be it bacteria or heavy metals) which stay inside the pipe.

Comment: Say what?  Replace the house piping?  That would cost sooo much money and involve a lot of demo.  Filtration would be the simplest and cheapest route.

Comment: @Gunner just very concern what is the situation inside the water pipe. (cause I also see slimy liquid coming out of the pipe connector)

Comment: Where are you located? What type of pipes? What is the water source? What filtration do you have now, if any, and When was the last time it was serviced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note, since you don't provide your location, my answer is based on a US water supply and building materials.

To answer the question that you asked, you don't replace the pipes in your house until they fail in some way (leaking), present a health hazard (.e.g lead pipes), or you need to move them for a renovation. Pipes are installed inside of the walls in such a way that they are not easy to access, which is one of the reasons that plumbing problems can be a difficult and expensive repair.

For the questions you didn't ask:

- If your fixtures are old, you may want to replace them with newer fixtures that will have new valves, clean aerators, along with a better look.
- If your water is bad, filter it. This solves the problem of bad water from your pipes (rare), bad fixtures, or from your water supply.
- If your kettle is rusty, replace it if the kettle itself is rusting. Otherwise, clean it and use filtered water.

Comment: Thanks BMitch for your answer. For my case, my water pipe is visible and is hang on the ceiling type. I do agree that using water filter is a much easy and faster way to solve but was concern on what is inside the water pipe when used for a period of time (5 years, 10 years or more) and would changing the water pipe and together with the water filter would be far better than just using water filter alone.